# Which one is more efficient `Object(value)` or `value || {}`

Tags: javascript, performance, object

I want to make sure that some certain variable is always an `Object` (I know that `aValue` can either be an `Object` or `undefined` or `null`). I have the following options:

```
var mustBeObject = aValue || {};
```

or

```
var mustBeObject = Object(aValue);
```

Which is the two is more efficient and why?

Comment: The first one doesn't achieve the goal. If it doesn't do what you want, who cares how efficient it is?

Comment: neither does the second one really... ex: Object(Date)

Comment: To see what I mean, try `aValue = 10` followed by your code.

Comment: Here's a comparison on jsperf http://jsperf.com/objcon Neither seem very sluggish (hundreds of millions of executions per second), but neither does what OP describes I think

Comment: I would *guess* that the first one.  As long as `aValue` is `truthy` (and it will be in a lot of cases) it will be just a simple assignment. In the second case it's always a function call. As it was pointed out by others, neither of them guarantee your logic.

Comment: @Barmar @dandavis I have edited the question such that it is now correct. The question is not about `aValue` but about the performance comparison between the 2 operations: `||` or `Object(...)`. Thanks @Wander Nauta ! I will add your jsperf test to the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to guarantee that `mustBeObject` is an object regardless of what `aValue` is, but if `aValue` is an object, then you want to use the value of `aValue`, then you will need a little more code:

```
var mustBeObject = (aValue && typeof aValue === "object") ? aValue : {};
```

Or, if you want to make sure that `aValue` is not even an array or other type of non JS object, you need even further testing to make sure `aValue` is what you want it to be:

```
// make sure it's an object and not an array and not a DOM object
function isPlainObject(item) {
    return (
        !!item &&
        typeof item === "object" && 
        Object.prototype.toString.call(item) === "[object Object]" &&
        !item.nodeType
    );
}

var mustBeObject = isPlainObject(aValue) ? aValue : {};
```

---

These where written to make sure that `mustBeObject` is a JS object regardless of what `aValue` is initially.  If you know from your code that `aValue` is only just `undefined` or a valid object, then your first option:

```
var mustBeObject = aValue || {};
```

will certainly be faster than any of my above options, but your option only protects against a falsey value in `aValue`, not other types of non-falsey values that are not JS objects, so since you said that you needed to "make sure that some certain variable is always an Object", I figured you needed more tests than just what you had.

---

A [jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/objcon) shows that the `OR` version is faster. Thanks to [@Wander Nauta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182402/wander-nauta)

Comment: The first snippet would have failed on nulls, unlike isPlainObject().

Comment: @Sacho - yeah, that is such a pain in JS that `typeof null === "object"`.  I will add an extra check for that.

Comment: I have edited my question such that there are less doubts about `aValue`